# Use begin..end or call to call stored procedures

Tags: database, oracle, jdbc, procedure

when I call a stored procedure in an Oracle Database from JDBC I have the following alternatives. Which one is recommended to be used and why?

1. prepareCall("{call MY_FUN}");
2. prepareCall"{BEGIN MY_FUN; END;}");

Thanks for your reply.

Regards Johannes

Comment: The `{` and `}` have a very specific meaning in JDBC (they are so called JDBC escapes), the second one is not a valid JDBC escape and I'd expect that to throw an exception.

Answer (score 5):

It depends. Using `begin..end`, you just call an anonymous PL/SQL program block, which in turn calls the stored procedure. When you use `call`, you call the procedure from SQL. Call has the additional benefit of having the possibility to return values and more. See [Oracle Database SQL Language Reference: Call](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_4008.htm) for more information.

That said, if you just call a procedure like this, there's not much of a difference. I think theoretically `begin..end` would be slightly more efficient, since the procedure itself is PL/SQL and `Call`, being SQL, would cause an extra context switch between SQL and PL/SQL which has some overhead. But I don't think you will notice this diffence if it even exists.

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to call exactly 1 procedure both statement are probably identical. Using an anonymous PLSQL block however allows you to have a lot more fun. Call more then one procedure for example or use any syntax that is allowed within a PLSQL block.

```
prepareCall("BEGIN MY_FUN('no-braces-with-begin-end-syntax'); MORE_FUN; A_LOT_MORE_FUN; END;");
```

Comment: What about calling function? For me calling one fucntion using `"{? = call func (?,?)}"` is not working. Strange

Comment: Search " how to call oracle function from java". You get 158 hits. If answer not there start a new question.

Answer (score -2):

You can use any type of procedure according to your requirement. Kindly clarify your requirement.